# R/Shiny/ggplot2: checkboxGroup to plot specific data

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Building from my last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327826/shiny-r-too-many-factors-on-line-graph/37331259#37331259) I want to use selectInput to allow users to plot as many regions as they wanna plot.

My data looks like this:

```
Year    Ratio   Region
1983 Q1 2.9 Northern
1983 Q2 3   Northern
1983 Q3 3.1 Northern
1983 Q4 3   Northern
...
2015 Q2 5.1 UK
2015 Q3 5.1 UK
2015 Q4 5.2 UK
2016 Q1 5.2 UK
```

server.R snippet

```
houseratio <- read.csv("houseratio.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  

output$housePlot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(data=houseratio[,input$region_choose], aes(x=Year, y=Ratio, group=Region, colour=Region)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
})
```

ui.r snippet

```
checkboxGroupInput("region_choose", label = "Choose a region",
          choices = c("The North"="Northern", "Yorkshire & Humber" = "Yorks & H",
                      "North West"="NW","East Midlands"="East Mids", 
                      "West Midlands"="West Mids", "East Anglia"="East Anglia",
                      "Outer South East"="Outer SE", "Outer Met"="Outer Met", 
                      "London"="London", "South West"="SW", "Wales"="Wales",
                      "Northern Ireland"="NI", "UK"="UK")
          ),

  plotOutput("housePlot")
)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163996/selectinput-and-plot-render) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462905/selectinput-as-argument-for-ggplot2) kinda helped but as my data is in long format it didn't seem to work (also because they're selectInput but weh).

Any help would be appreciated, if I've missed anything crucial- sorry, what is it?

Comment: Returns the error:
`Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1862, 0
Stack trace (innermost first):
    68: output$housePlot
     1: runApp`

Comment: Sorry I'm not au fait enough to know how to do this... Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I think your have problem in filter try

```
data=houseratio[houseratio$region%in%input$region_choose,]
```

2) better devide problem into 2 : data manipulation and plot see example

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(checkboxGroupInput("region_choose", label = "Choose a region",
                              choices = c("setosa","versicolor","virginica")
),

plotOutput("housePlot")
))

server=function(input,output){
  #data manipulation
  data_1=reactive({
    return(iris[iris$Species%in%input$region_choose,])
  })
  #plot
  output$housePlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=data_1(), aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Width, group=Species, colour=Species)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. So the issue was that I had not specified the data as being reactive?

Comment: No i think problem was in filter . `ggplot(data=iris[iris$Species%in%input$region_choose,], aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Width, group=Species, colour=Species))` also has to work good

Comment: I've managed to reproduce this effect with another project, thanks for your help!